# Back end ec2 instance is accessible through ssh and browser but fails load balancer health check

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I'm setting up a load balancer for the first time so please bear with me as I try to provide as much detail (I'll be checking back on this question every 15 minutes so I can speedily reply to any answers that request my clarification.)

I bought a domain from godaddy.com, but to my understanding configuring the load balancer would be more straight forward if I used amazon's DNS service Route 53.

To my understanding an alternative to using Route 53 would be to go to the godaddy control panel for `mydomain.com`, set an A record with the elastic ip of an instance that has a rewrite rule to forward all traffic from `mydomain.com` to `www.mydomain.com` and then a CNAME record `www` with the load balancer's address.  Ec2 advises not to set an A record for the load balancer's address since that actually address changes.

1. I launched an ec2 instance running ubuntu 12.04 and lamp-server. 
   `ec2-**-**-**-**.compute-1.amazonaws.com` is accessible from both
   the url and ssh.
2. I created a ec2 load balancer with a ping path of "/" but unfortunately
   my ec2 instance does not pass the health check for me to add the
   instance to the load balancer.
3. I created a hosted zone in Route 53 for my domain name.
4. I went into godaddy and removed the existing godaddy nameservers and
   added the 4 nameservers provided by route 53.
5. Finally I went into Route 53 and created an A record with an Alias
   Target to the load balancer's address
   **.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.

My end goal is when somebody goes to `mydomain.com` the url would be resolved by route 53 and the load balancer would direct traffic to an ec2 instance.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work? (Note: I completed step 5 about 12 hours ago, all DNS changes have propagated since `mydomain.com` loads a blank page instead of the godaddy template

**EDIT**

`curl -v localhost` returns `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

`curl -v abcloadbalancer-123124.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.` returns `HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity`

`curl -v mydomain.com` returns `HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity`

The security groups allow from port 80 anyways (0.0.0.0)

Comment: Check that your instance is returning HTTP 200 for the ping path (anything else is considered unhealthy). How are your security groups setup?

Comment: thx michael - How do I check that my ec2 instance is returning HTTP 200 for the ping path (ie what command do I use)?  The security group for my ec2 instance allows inbound tcp 22 and 80.  I have made no changes to the firewall on the ec2 instance.

Comment: On the CLI `curl -v <url>` will show the HTTP details (there should only be one request and response, i.e. no redirects). Otherwise Firebug in Firefox or something similar can show you that. Do the security groups allow port 80 from *anywhere* (i.e. including from ELB)?

Comment: `curl -v localhost` returns `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`,`
`curl -v abcloadbalancer-123124.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.` returns `HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity`
`curl -v mydomain.com` returns `HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity`,
The security groups allow from port 80 anyways (0.0.0.0)

Comment: You should rather edit your question when adding additional information. That response looks correct though. Check the [idle timeout](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ts-elb-healthcheck.html) issue mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Is the host name abcloadbalancer... the load balanced host name? If yes, then the 503 is most likely due to your ping test failing.  Is your web site up and running?

Comment: @mgorven - I set the response timeout to 55 seconds and the check interval to .98 mins.  I then did a hard refresh in firefox on 3 urls, the domain name, the load balancer address and the public ip of the ec2 instance.  The domain name and load balancer loaded a blank in the browser window page but the public ip of my ec2 instance loaded my website.

Comment: @HeatfanJohn - My website is up and running and can be accessed from the url http://ec2-*.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

Comment: @mgorven I set the value in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time` to be `720000` which is 200 hours.  That didn't do anything.  I rebooted the instance so now the default keepalive value is `7200` which is 2 hours, however the instance is still showing up as unhealthy.  Any more ideas?  Thx

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you've added the AWS ELB security group to your instance's security group to be able to access your instances.  If you're not allowing the world (0.0.0.0/0) to port 80, you'll need to specifically allow the AWS ELB SG or it wont be able to even hit your server to run the healthcheck.

If you're running on port 80, make sure that you allow **amazon-elb/sg-5a9c116a** (amazon-elb-sg) in the security group your instance belongs to.

If all of your instances are shown as unhealthy on the ELB, you'll see the 503 error.

Comment: Thanks Jason - I tried this and unfortunately it did not work.  I have tcp port 80 and 22 open to all 0.0.0.0/0 and ports 0-65535 open to amazon-elb yet the health check for my instance does not pass

Comment: Can you hit the URL configured in the ELB health check successfully directly on the servers?  The default healthcheck is /index.html, does that function on the servers in the ELB?

Comment: Do you see any requests in the Apache access log from the ELB at all?